# In react-dropdown-tree-select library checked items getting unselected after calling API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dropdown-tree-select

I am using react-dropdown-tree-select library to show the dropdowns like tree hierarchy.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsDZ8.png)

```
<TreeSelect
   resetGeographyFilter ={this.resetGeographyFilter.bind(this,"buttonClick")}
   applyGeographyFilter = {this.applyGeographyFilter.bind(this)}
   geographyData = {this.state.data}
   hideButtons = {this.hideButtons.bind(this)}
/>
```

On Apply button , I am calling below function.

```
applyGeographyFilter()
  {
    document.getElementsByClassName("buttonsContainer")[0].style.display = "none";
    this.appliedGeographies = JSON.parse(storage.getItemValue(keys.SELECTED_FILTERS))
    if(this.appliedGeographies!==null)
    {
      let requestObj = {
        status: [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
        govUserRoleType: storage.getItemValue(keys.ADMIN_TYPE),
        govUserRoleName: this.state.selectedRoleName,
        productId: Number(storage.getItemValue(keys.PRODUCT_ID)),
        applicationsFilterList: {
            "application_data": {
                "geography_filter": this.appliedGeographies,
            }
          }
      }
      this.apiCall = true;
      this.props.getApplicationCountWithFilterApi(requestObj);
    }
    this.hideButtons()
  }
```

In which I am calling getApplicationCountWithFilterApi , but after calling this API My checked values data getting reset.

https://www.veed.io/view/7dd01565-6161-486d-bcdc-50fa1fed4053?sharingWidget=true&panel=share

However, if I comment this line //this.props.getApplicationCountWithFilterApi(requestObj); in applyGeographyFilter() function , its working fine.

I tried checking if the page is getting re-render apply clicking on the apply button,by consoling in componentDidMount, but page is not getting re-render.